# Raspbian-Boot: Failed to start light display

Tags: linux, boot, raspbian

For some reason when I booted up my pi today, I'm getting the error 'Failed to start light manager. When I look at the details I see these errors:

[image: Photo of error on physical display]

Any idea's what is causing this and how I could fix this?

I've tried

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install aptitude
 sudo aptitude reinstall lightdm
```

also

```
sudo aptitude install gdm
```

Every time I reboot I get the blank screen with blinking cursor, in which I press ctrl alt f1 to return to the boot page and see the same error.

I have basically zero linux or raspbian knowledge, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: This should be moved to the rasperry pi SE site

Comment: I have exact same issue with latest Raspbian Jessie Lite image.